# How to compile and run assembler source from the command prompt?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, assembly, command-line

I have this relatively simple program in `C`
which prints the sum of two `ints`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 8;
    printf("a + b = %d", a+b);
    getchar();
}
```

I generated the assembly code using this command: `gcc -S prog.c` to get the assembly code.

```
    .file   "prog.c"
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "a + b = %d\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB10:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $5, 28(%esp)
    movl    $8, 24(%esp)
    movl    28(%esp), %edx
    movl    24(%esp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    call    _getchar
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE10:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.3.0"
    .def    _printf;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _getchar;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

How do I run this `prog.s` from command line? All searches led to running this on Linux using `asm` and `fasm` commands which are not recognized by my `cmd`.

My OS: Windows 10

Comment: You don't *"run"* assembly code. It's a human-readable programming language, that assemblers can assemble into object code, which is then fed into a linker to produce an executable image. It's just like C code, which likewise cannot be *"run"* from the command line.

Comment: It is just your .c file in another programming language you still need to assemble and link it.  The gnu tools actually allow you to do this using the c compiler you should be able to feed this into gcc and it will understand it is assembly language and not C and once assembled will then call the linker for you as it does when you feed it a .c file.  And ideally link it for your target host so it just runs.  You can then for example in the assembly language modify the ascii string add some more characters to the a + b, re-run through gcc to see that it is really this asm that is being used.

Comment: @old_timer. `gcc prog.s` generated an executable file. I ran it and got expected result. Then I changed the `a` in assembly code from 5 to 6 and typed the command again. Ran the modified `.exe` and got `14`. THANKS! I was sure it was the machine code my CPU is about to run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just your .c file in another programming language you still need to assemble and link it. The gnu tools actually allow you to do this using the c compiler you should be able to feed this into gcc and it will understand it is assembly language and not C and once assembled will then call the linker for you as it does when you feed it a .c file. And ideally link it for your target host so it just runs. You can then for example in the assembly language modify the ascii string add some more characters to the a + b, re-run through gcc to see that it is really this asm that is being used.